# Monte Carlo with rates, system simulation with CUDA C++

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, gpu

So I am trying to simulate a 1-D physical model named Tasep.

I wrote a code to simulate this system in c++, but I definitely need a performance boost.

The model is very simple ( c++ code below ) - an array of `1`'s and `0`'s. **`1`** represent a particle and **`0`** is no-particle, meaning empty. A particle moves one element to the right, at a rate `1`, if that element is empty. A particle at the last location will disappear at a rate `beta` ( say 0.3 ). Finally, if the first location is empty a particle will appear there, at a rate `alpha`.

One threaded is easy, I just pick an element at random, and act with probability `1 / alpha / beta`, as written above. But this can take a lot of time.

So I tried to do a similar thing with many threads, using the GPU, and that raised a lot of questions:

1. Is using the GPU and CUDA at all good idea for such a thing?
2. How many threads should I have? I can have a thread for each site ( **`10E+6`** ), should I?
3. How do I synchronize the access to memory between different threads? I used atomic operations so far.
4. What is the right way to generate random data? If I use a million threads is it ok to have a random generator for each?
5. How do I take care of the rates?

I am very new to CUDA. I managed to run code from CUDA samples and some tutorials.  Although I have some code of the above ( still gives strange result though ), I do not put it here, because I think the questions are more general.

So here is the c++ one threaded version of it:

```
int Tasep()
{
    const int L = 750000;

    // rates
    int alpha = 330;
    int beta  = 300;
    int ProbabilityNormalizer = 1000;

    bool system[L];
    int pos = 0;
    InitArray(system); // init to 0's and 1's

    /* Loop */
    for (int j = 0; j < 10*L*L; j++)
    {
        unsigned long randomNumber = xorshf96();
        pos = (randomNumber % (L)); // Pick Random location in the the array

        if (pos == 0 && system[0] == 0) // First site and empty
            system[0] = (alpha > (xorshf96() % ProbabilityNormalizer)); // Insert a particle with chance alpha

        else if (pos == L - 1) // last site
            system[L - 1] = system[L - 1] && (beta < (xorshf96() % ProbabilityNormalizer)); // Remove a particle if exists with chance beta

        else if (system[pos] && !system[pos + 1]) // If current location have a particle and the next one is empty - Jump right
        {
            system[pos] = false;
            system[pos + 1] = true;
        }
        if ((j % 1000) == 0) // Just do some Loggingg
            Log(system, j);
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I would be truly grateful for whoever is willing to help and give his/her advice.

Answer (score -2):

I think that your goal is to perform something called Monte Carlo Simulations.
But I have failed to fully understand your main objective (i.e. get a frequency, or average power lost, etc.)

**Question 01**

Since you asked about random data, I do believe you can have multiple random seeds (maybe one for each thread), I would advise you to generate the seed in the GPU using any pseudo random generator (you can use even the same as CPU), store the seeds in GPU global memory and launch as many threads you can using dynamic parallelism. 
So, yes CUDA is a suitable approach, but keep in your mind the balance between time that you will require to learn and how much time you will need to get the result from your current code. 
If you will take use this knowledge in the future, learn CUDA maybe worth, or if you can escalate your code in many GPUs and it is taking too much time in CPU and you will need to solve this equation very often it worth too. Looks like that you are close, but if it is a simple one time result, I would advise you to let the CPU solve it, because probably, from my experience, you will take more time learning CUDA than the CPU will take to solve it (IMHO).

**Question 02**

The number of threads is very usual question for rookies. The answer is very dependent of your project, but taking in your code as an insight, I would take as many I can, using every thread with a different seed.
My suggestion is to use registers are what you call "sites" (be aware that are strong limitations) and then run multiples loops to evaluate your particle, in the very same idea of a car tire a bad road (data in SMEM), so your L is limited to 255 per loop (avoid spill at your cost to your project, and less registers means more warps per block). To create perturbation, I would load  vectors in the shared memory, one for alpha (short), one for beta (short) (I do assume different distributions), one "exist or not particle" in the next site (char), and another two to combine as pseudo generator source with threadID, blockID, and some current time info (to help you to pick the initial alpha, beta and exist or not) so u can reuse this rates for every thread in the block, and since the data do not change (only the reading position change) you have to sync only once after reading, also you can "random pick the perturbation position and reuse the data. The initial values can be loaded from global memory and "refreshed" after an specific number of loops to hide the loading latency. In short, you will reuse the same data in shared multiple times, but the values selected for every thread change at every interaction due to the pseudo random value. Taking in account that you are talking about large numbers and you can load different data in every block, the pseudo random algorithm should be good enough. Also, you can even use the result stored in the gpu from previous runs as random source, flip one variable and do some bit operations, so u can use every bit as a particle.

**Question 03**

For your specific project I would strongly recommend to avoid thread cooperation and make these completely independent. But, you can use shuffle inside the same warp, with no high cost.

**Question 04**

It is hard to generate truly random data, but you should worry about by how often last your period (since any generator has a period of random and them repeats). I would suggest you to use a single generator which can work in parallel to your kernel and use it feed your kernels (you can use dynamic paralelism). In your case since you want some random you should not worry a lot with consistency. I gave an example of pseudo random data use in the previous question, that may assist. Keep in your mind that there is no real random generator, but there are alternatives as internet bits for example.

**Question 05**

Already explained in the Question 03, but keep in your mind that you do not need a full sequence of values, only a enough part to use in multiple forms, to give enough time to your kernel just process and then you can refresh you sequence, if you guarantee to not feed block with the same sequence it will be very hard to fall into patterns.

Hope I have help, I’m working with CUDA for a bit more than a year, started just like you, and still every week I do improve my code, now it is almost good enough. Now I see how it perfectly fit my statistical challenge: cluster random things.

Good luck!